# I have issue with permission check in higher versions of android

Tags: android, android-permissions, runtime-permissions

I have a problem with permission check in higher versions of android.I am checking all permission but still app crash on 6.0 .

This is my java code :

```
  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M  &&
               checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS}, 0);
        requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, 0);
        requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE}, 0);
        requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
        requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, 0);
        requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WAKE_LOCK}, 0);
        requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 0);
        requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        jump_to_nextActivity();
    }


}

public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)
{
    //super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    for (int i = 0, len = permissions.length; i < len; i++)
    {
        String permission = permissions[i];
        if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
        {
            flag = false;
        }
    }
    if(flag==true)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this,Home.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        //i.putExtra("EXIT", true);
        startActivity(i);
        Splash.this.finish();
    }
}
```

This is my Android Manifest:

```
     <permission
    android:name="android.OMMSoftware.Navsahydri.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.OMMSoftware.Navsahydri.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="fractal5.mythirdapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
```

App is running on lower versions but when test it on 6.0 it crash, Please help.

This is My Logcat:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: android.inclusiveit.growbizz, PID: 16919
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has extras) }} to activity {android.inclusiveit.growbizz/android.OMMSoftware.Navsahydri.Splash}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()' on a null object reference
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3949)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3992)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1543)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5776)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()' on a null object reference
                                                       at android.OMMSoftware.Navsahydri.Splash.onRequestPermissionsResult(Splash.java:54)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult(Activity.java:6969)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6848)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3945)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3992) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1543) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5776) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)

Comment: what error its giving in console? use try catch to find error.

Comment: why nobody post their stacktrace anymore? are we supposed to guess the error?

Comment: Post you stack trace-log cat with error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible cause of error could the one that, you haven't declared all the required permissions into `manifest.xml` file.

> Note that if you are requesting permission that is not declared into
>   `manifest.xml`, it will always returned as `denied` by the system iteself.

One more thing, why are you checking all the permission at once? *Instead what you can do is, check the permission at runtime while your function requires permission to be granted by system.*

Further, **There is no need to put `android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M`** condition as you have - 

**`ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()` method which returns the result accordingly even in lower api versions.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention the permission classified as "Dangerous" by Android documentation separately in the Manifest. Here's an example:

```
<permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
    android:protectionLevel="dangerous" />
```

You can see the whole list of normal and dangerous permissions [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#normal-dangerous)

Answer (score 0):

Here you are checking only READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, please all Dangerous Permissions which you declare in manifest. like ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

Answer (score 0):

The error is on your Manifest permissions.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.OMMSoftware.Navsahydri.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="fractal5.mythirdapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
```

As these permissions are not recognized by Android just remove them.

Answer (score 0):

When Android released it Marshmallow version it introduced Runtime permissions as one of its features. The feature includes taking permission from the user while accessing location, camera, gallery, contacts and so on. So every time the user tries to access any of the above, let us consider Camera in our case, it will ask for a permission. The pop up will say Need permission to access your camera, whether it should Allow or deny. If you deny and check the checkbox never ask again, user won't is able to access the camera throughout the Application. The user needs to install again for the popup. User can grant permission by 2 ways: either by settings or by the popup. To make it more user-friendly we inserted pop up in our app

For instance, you are checking permission for Location, use this code inside onMapReady method

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        {
            if (MapLayoutActivity.this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                MapLayoutActivity.this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_STORAGE);
                return;
            }

            if (MapLayoutActivity.this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                MapLayoutActivity.this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_STORAGE);
                return;
            }
        }
```